# How to search a pattern in a file using c skills? or how to read line on line from a file in c?

Tags: c

I want to read a text file line on line and search for the required pattern.For example the pattern "hello" to be searched in a file named File1.txt. Is that possible using c skills?must return 0 if it does not find hello and 1 if it finds hello in the file1.txt.Any ideas to do that?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it's probably not the best tool for the job and it is rather re-inveting the wheel when tools like grep and "scripting" languages like Perl et al with regex support will already do this kind of thing for you.

Comment: reinventing gives you a good knowledge over the invented things

Comment: If you cant answer be quite guys dont put downvotes its not a useless question.

Comment: If you think it has nothing to do then give the solution i go with u

Comment: You dont have the right solution with you but you give downvotes you dont worth to give downvotes when you dont know the answer thats it

Comment: There are a number of people at SO whose only contribution is to call everything homework ... and they think they're clever for it.

Comment: you are right Jim so many people just say the outline and go out saying your homework or some other stuff.But we know those outlines we want some knowledge from them.I hope everybody understands it

Comment: @Jim, I was asking whether it was homework so that he could either add the "homework" tag or indicate that it was not homework. The way in which the question was asked and the level of complexity of the question made it sound suspiciously like homework. It's not a matter of being "clever", but rather maintaining professional ethics and discouraging cheating which, unfortunately, is rather widespread in the field of computer science relative to other disciplines.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan  You're simply confirming my charge.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can do pretty much anything in C. Open the file, read it character by character (byte by byte), check if it is the first letter in your search key ('h'), if it is, check if it is the next letter and so on.

EDIT: Pseudo code

```
const char key[] = "hello";
bool found_key = false;

open file
handle errors if not open    

while not end of file
{
  i=0;
  do
  {
    ch = read 1 character;

    if(ch == key[i])
    {
      if(i==sizeof(key))
      {
        found_key = true;
        break;
      } 
      i++;
    }
  } while(ch == key[i]); 
}
```

I would regard any solution involving saving more than 1 char in RAM as quite suspicious.

Comment: lol doesnot it sound so problametic ?

Comment: i know it using putc but if the pattern is too big like 20 letters ?it gets u in trouble speed decreases

Comment: fgets(), read and evaluate one character at a time.

Comment: the code gets bigger and bigger

Comment: Umm, no? You should be able to write make this code both efficient and compact. I'll edit my answer with some pseudo code.

Comment: This doesn't work if the key contains its first character more than once. You really need something like Boyer-Moore or Knuth–Morris–Pratt. Example: key=aab, text=aaab

Comment: P.S. Boyer-Moore is "sublinear" ... it doesn't have to look at every character. e.g., if the key is "hello" and the fifth char of the text is 'x', the key can't start in any of the first five chars ... if the 10th char also isn't in the key, one can skip again, and so on, potentially only looking at every fifth char. Searching for longer keys is actually *faster* than searching for shorter ones.

Comment: @Jim Err... it does work no matter what the search key happens to be, because this algorithm checks string length and contents both. This algorithm would also work for pure binary data. This is just pseudo code though, I didn't test it and you'll need to refine it. You need Boyer-Moore for this like you need a bazooka to kill flies.

Comment: @Lundin I gave you a key and text that don't work; try it out yourself. Your algorithm will consume the first two 'a's, and never backtrack to find that the key starts at the second 'a'. Arrogance is no substitute for algorithmic correctness.

Comment: Here's another example that better illustrates the problem with your "save only 1 char" limitation: key=hellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhello text=hellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhello

Comment: @Jim You'd have to store a pointer to where you started comparing, so that you can revert to there if you don't find the string. And no, this won't be effective for enormous amounts of ridiculous data, but the argument here is that reading one byte from disk likely takes thousand times longer than doing a byte comparison. So you can't really lift this to some fuzzy theoretic level, you have to take the hardware in account.

Comment: @Lundin "You'd have to store a pointer to where you started comparing, so that you can revert to there" -- which means storing that data in memory ... just as Boyer-Moore requires, but it's faster. It's also practical, not "fuzzy theoretic" -- that's loaded language that makes for bad thinking.

Comment: I think i should contact MR dennis and kernighan to solve it.

Comment: @Jim So you honestly think that a CPU 8 bit comparison is equally efficient as a disk read through the whole stdio (and thereby through the OS API)? Instead of posting arrogant comments, perhaps you could post a solution of your own? Make sure you clock it with the API of your system too, so you take disk access time in account.

Comment: @Lundin "So you honestly think that a CPU 8 bit comparison is equally efficient as a disk read through the whole stdio (and thereby through the OS API)?" -- I can't quite make out how you have so grossly miscomprehended what I wrote. "Instead of posting arrogant comments" -- pot/kettle/black. "perhaps you could post a solution of your own?" -- I posted a reference to Boyer-Moore and Knuth-Morris-Pratt which, unlike your algorithm, actually work on arbitrary keys.

Comment: Finally, "You'd have to store a pointer to where you started comparing, so that you can revert to there if you don't find the string" is essentially the same as doing a strcmp at each byte, which Lundin railed against. Now he excuses extra comparisons by comparing them to disk reads, while he previously complained about it being "very inefficient" to buffer data and do repeated comparisons. The irony is bizarre. The truth is that if you don't care about the relatively small costs, you can use strstr, and if you do you can use Boyer-Moore. But don't use Lundin's algorithm, which doesn't work.

Comment: ok jim and im glad to say that  i found my way to do it on my own.I have written 3 codes in c now.One code is to search the pattern and the second one is to say how many times the pattern is repeated in the file and third one prints all the patterns precedded with given pattern hurray i made it and u cant belive it the code is just 12 lines and i used the malloc functions to save memory all together it costs 5 bytes for variables and some bytes for code.and even it works much faster i have done it using the getc and strcmp but in a different way compared to boyer moore and Thank you for all

Answer (score 3):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) provides [regcomp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html), [regexec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regexec.html), [regfree](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regfree.html), and friends for regular expression matching. If you are using C++, then you can use the [RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) library for faster, safer regular expression matching. If all you need to do is find an exact match like "hello", you won't even need a regex library like these.

Yes, this is something you can do with C, but I won't do your homework for you.

Comment: its not a homework its a project im trying to do on my own

Comment: you wont do because you dont know the solution dude i understand don try to escape.Why dont u just say i cant do it.?

Comment: @cody, the way in which you asked the question made it sound like homework, which is why I declined to provide code. There are a lot of students who come here to cheat, by demanding answers to their homework questions without putting in any effort, so please understand my refusal to give you a complete code solution. Even with your affirmation that it isn't homework, I am now rather disinclined to give you one given that a.) the way you originally asked for a solution was a demand and not a polite request and b.) you just now insulted me, rather than explaining that it was not homework.

Comment: @cody, if it is just a project, I strongly suggest using grep.

Comment: sorry Aaron i was little frustrated because there is no one that can help me out here and my words came out so wrong i apologise you for that.I am really sorry if my question sounds like a demanding one.Its not a homework but rather im tryin to create own library and use it my file applications or develop some software on files.I have written that code using perl script but i wanted to know is it possible using c.If it then i can use it in c functions.But im glad to say i did it on my own and thanks for your cooperation Aaron

Answer (score 3):

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *f;
   char buffer[100];
   char *pattern = "hello";

   if (argc != 2) {
      // provide filename as first argument
      return 0;
   }

   if ((f = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
      // file not found
      return 0;
   }

   while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f)) {
      if (strstr(buffer, pattern)) {
         return 1;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

build:

```
gcc demo.c
```

usage:

```
./a.out 1.txt
echo $?
1

./a.out 2.txt
echo $?
0
```

Comment: man its wrong u cant say the file size is 100 bytes it might be 200 bytes and  the pattern might be at 130 byte how u manage it in some cases the file size may be 2 mb how u do it ?

Comment: where did you see that the file size restricted to 100 bytes? this is just a buffer size that will be read each time in gets function until end of file. this is just a skeleton code (not universal solution) you can enhance it according to your requirements :)

Comment: This code is very inefficient both in terms of speed and memory. Read the characters one by one.

Comment: :) there where no any mention in question that the code should be optimized for embedded systems ))) I suppose it will be pretty fast and not so memory inefficient even for i386 :)

Comment: a) Cody is right that this code won't work for a key that's bigger than the input buffer (e.g., a 100 byte buffer and a 130 byte key). b) A 100 byte buffer is not "very inefficient". c) Lundin's "read the characters one by one" algorithm does not work for all keys (see my comment on his answer). d) This is why the Boyer-Moore and Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithms were invented.

Comment: Thanks Jim, a) it is obvious that the code will not work with key more than 100 bytes (so I advised to enhanced it according to requirements) b) agree, of course it be better to read os/disk subsystem defined atomic block for reading operation

Comment: For an improvement to the already highly efficient Boyer-Moore algorithm, see the link to the Sustik-Moore algorithm at the bottom of http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/best-ideas/string-searching/

Comment: The only problem with this code is if the word being searched for falls across the boundary between 99-byte chunks of the file - it will miss those.  (For example, if byte 97 is 'h', byte 98 is 'e', byte 99 is 'l', byte 100 is 'l' and byte 101 is 'o'.)  Oh, and it won't work if the string to search for is longer than 99 bytes (clearly not a problem with the fixed search string of "hello").

Comment: Note that you can avoid losing matches if you move the last N-1 bytes of the previous buffer (where N is the length of the pattern) to the start before reading M-(N-1) more bytes from the file (where M is the number of bytes the buffer can hold.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in C skill. Use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) to read the file and use <strike>strcmp()</strike> [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) to find if the read data contains the pattern you're looking for.

Comment: However, note that reading the whole file and then searching with strcmp() is very very inefficient.

Comment: You want `strstr`, not `strcmp`; that's O(N), which is optimal.... Hah, user478681 beat me to it, and with a full solution yet.

Comment: your right lundin so theres no way to do it in 10 lines using c?

Comment: i wanna create as a library and use it in my project.I am creating my own pattern searching library with powerfull features then i include it in c library it would be useful

Comment: No it isn't O(N), you compare each character several times. Imagine if the file is cluttered with the word "hell"... you'd first have to compare 4 characters, then as you realize it isn't the search string, iterate by increasing the pointer by 1, compare "ell". Because you cannot assume that an incorrect string does not contain parts of the search key, unless you write a very complex algorithm. Further, strstr(...) is equally inefficient as  strcmp(moving_pointer,...). Most importantly: why on earth do you want to store the whole dang file in RAM!?

Comment: @jim balter: thanks. edited. i think i'm forgetting C. :(
@lundin: i didn't mean to read whole file into RAM.

Comment: @Lundin You're right, `strstr` is inefficient, but Boyer–Moore, which isn't, and takes account of the issues you point out, is not "very complex". Also, reading the file with `fgets` does not store the whole file in RAM.

Comment: @Jim Boyer-Moore assumes the string is already present in RAM. The nature of file reading is linear, left to right. I don't see how Boyer-Moore would any anything but needless complexity (it -is- complex compared to a one byte comparison). If you implement this with simple linear search char by char, and clock & compare against Boyer-Moore, I reckon you'd find the latter far more inefficient.

Comment: @Lundin That you don't see things is not a virtue. As I pointed out in my comment on your answer, your algorithm doesn't work for some keys ... and what you "reckon" is simply wrong; such profiling *has* been done; Boyer-Moore is a big win for long keys. Here's clue: disk reads happen in chunks bigger than a char at a time; consider `mmap`.

Comment: Beware of the word appearing across buffer boundaries.  Also, `strstr()` is frequently not as slow as some people seem to think it is.  Benchmark it.  I've benchmarked `strstr()` against my own BM and KMP algorithms, and lost.  I'm still mortified by that; I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but `strstr()` is not always a slouch.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Some `strstr` implementations apparently *are* BM or KMP or use algorithms of similar sophistication.